# Take output of array, and put into new array (perl script)

Tags: perl, array

I have an array set up to check different workstations to see if any logs are present, and if logs are present, to delete them. The problem is, every time I execute the script, it has to crawl through all the workstations every single time (the command to remove the logs only does so 1 at a time). Is there a way to check all of the workstations the first time, and if logs are present, to set up the next array to check only those with logs present? And so on and so forth until none are left? It takes a bit of time to check through 100 different workstations when only 10 or so have logs. Here is what I have so far (Unix AIX, and perl v5.6.1):

```
my @workstation = qw(ws1 ws2 ws3 ws4 ws5 ws6 ws7 ws8 ws9 ws10 ws11 ws12);

foreach my $workstation (@workstation){
$logcount = `ssh -q $workstation "ls /logs/$workstation | wc -l"`;
chomp $logcount;

if($logcount == 0){
print "";
}

if($logcount > 0){
print "$workstation: $count\n";
`ssh -q $workstation "/tools/log_remover /logs/$workstation"`
}
```

Comment: You are launching 2 ssh calls where one would be enough, and that will slow things down,  but I don't understand what you man by "the next array". You are only going through the array once.

Comment: If, for instance, only workstations 2,5,8 still have logs, I only want to send those through the same log_remover.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: why not just do something like: `ssh -q $workstation "count=$(ls /logs/$workstation | wc -l) ; [ $count -gt 0 ] && /tools/log_remover /logs/$workstation"`?  or install `pdsh` (Parallel Distributed Shell) from https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html - if you're writing for-loop wrappers around ssh then `pdsh` is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Why to check the count if you just want to delete them? Delete the files directly. Plain simple bash version to remove logs older than 7 days:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS=( ws1 ws2 ws3 ws4 ws5 ws6 ws7 ws8 ws9 ws10 ws11 ws12 )

for CURRHOST in ${HOSTS[@]}
do
    ssh -q $CURRHOST "find /logs/$CURRHOST -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -v {} \;"
done
```

If you insist in using perl and want to fill an array containing hosts which have logfiles you can use:

```
my @workstation = qw(ws1 ws2 ws3 ws4 ws5 ws6 ws7 ws8 ws9 ws10 ws11 ws12);
my %wscount;

foreach my $workstation (@workstation){
  $logcount = `ssh -q $workstation "ls /logs/$workstation | wc -l"`;
  chomp $logcount;
  if ( $logcount > 0 )
  {
    $wscount{$workstation}=$logcount;
  }
}

foreach my $wswithlog (keys %wscount){
  printf "host $wswithlog: $wscount{$wswithlog}\n";
  `ssh -q $wswithlog "/tools/log_remover /logs/$wswithlog"`
}
```